# pointerEvent = "none" will not disable a input tag

Tags: javascript

Trying to use `pointerEvents = "none";` to disable a insert from being typable. It doesn't seem to be working at all. 'actual' doesn't work when being disabled either.

```js
function enter() {
  document.getElementById('actual').pointerEvents = "none";
}
```

```html
<div id="actual">
  <div id="mastsactual"><input id="sign1" disabled></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you call your function? Also, there's no such thing as `</input>`. Finally, a disabled input can't be typed in anyway, so what's the real issue?

Comment: Didn't get what you really want!

Comment: edited it with the proper HTML used, it is working after i applied the previous answer that was deleted.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course `#actual` doesn't "work" anymore since you're applying `pointerEvents='none'` to it.

If you just want to disable the `input` element, try the following:

```js
function enter() {
  element = document.getElementById('sign1')
  element.disabled = element.disabled ? false : true
  button = document.getElementById('button')
  button.value = button.value === 'Disable Input' ? 'Enable Input' : 'Disable Input'
}
```

```html
<div id="actual">
  <div id="mastsactual">
    <input id="sign1" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
<input id="button" type="button" onClick=enter() value="Disable Input">
```

Calling the `enter` function will toggle the state of the `sign1`, so that if it is enabled it will become disable, and vice-versa.